# Get all employees count whose first name starts alphabetically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

In TSQL how do i get the starting letter of the fname of the employee and number of employee with that letter. I got to do this on `PUBS` database

`select ASCII(fname) 'ASCII CODE',SUBSTRING(fname,1,1) 'LETTER' from employee`

#### Output

```
65  A
65  A
65  A
65  A
67  C
67  C
68  D
68  D
69  E
..      ..
```

#### Expecting output

```
10  A
20  B
30  C
..  ..
```

Since it involved a Grouping by first letter of fname i had included `groupby fname` but no change in output. What is the exact SQL i need to run ?

Comment: by the way note that ASCII code was just used here for no purpose. So don't confuse over it

Comment: If it's used for no purpose and could cause confusion why include it here at all?

Comment: @RThomas Sorry it is easy to copy, paste code. But hell of time waste to edit here on SO

Comment: I might recommend considering the time spent by people willing to help you out who have to decipher what your asking - if `time waste` is your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(fname,1), COUNT(1) 
FROM employee
GROUP BY LEFT(fname,1)
```

Edit: Damn! Ninja'd - SO can be a bit slow to update sometimes lol

Answer (score 1):

Just need to group by the two columns you selected ...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(fname,1,1) 'LETTER', COUNT(*) cnt
FROM employee
GROUP BY (fname,1,1)
```

Comment: You had understood question incorrectly. I want FirstLetter of employee and then Count of number of employees whose first letter is that. I added a comment too that ASCII code does not mean anything here

Comment: @Deeptechtons gotcha.  Fixed my answer, but I think JumpingJezza beat me to the punch.